# Mifare ultraligtht and APDU commands

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare, apdu

I am looking for a list over various APDU commands, supported by the mifare ultralight cards,
I have tried to search for how to lock bytes, making them permanently readonly, but so far unable to find anything, is it even possible to set any of these blocks to readonly, or is there even a permanently reset card to 0 ?

thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the information you are looking for are in the document "NFC Forum Type 2 Tag Operation Specification 1.1"

Here is a copy:

http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf

In general, if you are looking for technical details, try the NFC Forum specifications first. You'll find pretty much everything NFC related in them.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether by using APDU command you mean 'command' or 'ISO/IEC 7816-4' APDU command.

But Mifare ultraligtht does not support ISO/IEC 14443-4 so they cannot support 'ISO/IEC 7816-4/smartcard' APDU.
See this Mifare family comparison table to see which Mifare support APDU: http://cache.nxp.com/documents/line_card/MIFARE_ICs_939775017001_v9_HR.pdf

As said in another message, have a look at NFC Type 2 (http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf).
Or have a look at one of the Mifare Ultralight datasheet: http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF0ICU2.pdf.